# How to invoke firebase Schedule functions locally using pubsub emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on cloud functions especially schedule functions. I need to trigger a function periodically each 5 minutes, but in only test step. I need to run it on pubsub emulator without deploying it.

How to do it?

I tried to use firebase shell, but it triggered only once

```
 exports.scheduledFunctionPlainEnglish =functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes')
 .onRun((context) => {
    functions.logger.log("this runs every 2 minutes")
    return null;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported for scheduled functions.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) states:

> Using the shell, you mock data and perform function calls to simulate interaction with products that the Emulator Suite does not currently support: Storage, **PubSub**, Analytics, Remote Config, Storage, Auth, and Crashlytics.

Scheduled functions are an unsupported extension of pubsub triggers.

Feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Here's the [open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2034) on GitHub.

Comment: Hi, is this still the case?

Answer (score 14):

Scheduled functions are loaded to the Cloud Functions emulator runtime and are bound to the PubSub emulator topic.

But as @samstern said (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2034):

> you'd have to manually trigger them using a Pub/Sub message.

You can do it like this:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub';

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}

const pubsub = new PubSub({
  apiEndpoint: 'localhost:8085' // Change it to your PubSub emulator address and port
});

setInterval(() => {
  const SCHEDULED_FUNCTION_TOPIC = 'firebase-schedule-yourFunctionName';
  console.log(`Trigger sheduled function via PubSub topic: ${SCHEDULED_FUNCTION_TOPIC}`);
  const msg = await pubsub.topic(SCHEDULED_FUNCTION_TOPIC).publishJSON({
    foo: 'bar',
  }, { attr1: 'value1' });
}, 5 * 60 * 1000); // every 5 minutes
```

Additional info about this concept (thanks to @kthaas):

1. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2011/files#diff-6b2a373d8dc24c4074ee623d433662831cadc7c178373fb957c06bc12c44ba7b
2. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2011/files#diff-73f0f0ab73ffbf988f109e0a4c8b3b8a793f30ef33929928a892d605f0f0cc1f

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, there are two more things in order for this code snippet to work. First, the `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` env variable has to be set to something like `localhost:8432` (depending on your local emulator setup). Second, the project id has to be given to the PubSub constructor (e.g. `new PubSub({ projectId: '...' }) `)

Comment: @Stephan I added `apiEndpoint` to the PubSub initialization. Instead of specifying `projectId` I use `env-cmd` with `.env` file containing a link to the default credentials `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./default-credentials.json`

Comment: How did this not have any votes before mine? This works perfectly! I created a js file (instead of a ts file to not have to worry about compiling it) with code borrowed from your answer and am triggering the task manually instead of in an interval like this: `node functions/src/myTriggerfile.js`

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov can you explain this ans more detaily? Because I tried to put setInterval in global scope but not working

Comment: I achive this by enable pubsub emulator in emulator suite and create a small node.js instance separately that only publish to topic like above example. Best approach I can find so far.

Comment: Hi, is pubsub still not working on localhost:4000?

Answer (score 9):

As you said, you can use firebase shell to run your function once.
And in firebase shell, you can use NodeJS commands.

## Use setInterval

Inside `firebase functions:shell`, use `setInterval` to run your function every 2 minutes.

```sh
user@laptop:~$ firebase functions:shell

✔  functions: functions emulator started at http://localhost:5000
i  functions: Loaded functions: myScheduledFunction
firebase > setInterval(() => myScheduledFunction(), 120000)

> this runs every 2 minutes
```

### Single line script

> Since version 8.4.3 of firebase-tools, and especially [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2350), the pipe solution does not work anymore.

In Bash, you can even pipe the `setInterval` command to firebase shell

```sh
user@laptop:~$ echo "setInterval(() => myScheduledFunction(), 120000)" | firebase functions:shell
```

Comment: Since version 8.4.3 of firebase-tools, and especially [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2350), this solution does not work anymore.

Comment: for clarification, you mean the single line pipe to shell doesn't work? (Then that could be edited from the answer?) I'm using fireabse-tools `9.16.0` and interactively running `setInterval(` in the shell works for me.

Comment: I realy like this solution, thanks. Didn't wanna create another file and run it. This makes it much easier

Answer (score 1):

For those of you seeing this in 2023, it's still not supported.

My solution was to abstract the code that does the "work" out of `functions.pubsub.schedule` and into their own functions. Then create a separate file (i added it at the top of the functions folder) with a `setInterval` inside it that fires the aforementioned abstracted function.

For example, somewhere in your code:

```
exports.myScheduledFunctionCode = () => {
  console.log('why, hello there interval');
}
```

And in the `timers.js` (for example) file at the top of the `/functions` directory:

```
setInterval(() => {
  myScheduledFunctionCode();
}, 60000);
```

Then, you can fire up your Firebase Emulator suite. In another Terminal session, just run a vanilla `$ node functions/timers.js`. Now your scheduled function code is running, and your whole emulator suite too.

Hope this helps someone!