# Cannot find pubsub in firebase init

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-cli

im trying to run a scheduled function in firebase emulator but cannot find the pubsub option when I run firebase init. Refer pic below
[image]

The options I get are Realtime Database, Firestore, Functions, Hosting, Storage, Emulators and Remote Config, there is no pubsub.

Comment: You may refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators).

Answer (score 2):

"pubsub" functions are created using cloud functions. It is part of Cloud Functions.
You only have to initialize(init) Functions.
Write the pubsub triggers there. View documentation for extra details on how to code pubsub - [DOCS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

Comment: I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253788/how-to-use-firebase-emulators-pubsub-to-test-timed-functions-locally . I followed the top comment, it says to select pubsub after running firebase init, I can't find pubsub after running firebase init

Comment: You do not need to select pubsub separately. Select Cloud Functions and start writing your "pubsub" code in "index.js"  file in "functions" folder.