# How do you handle a short webhook timeout? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-cloud-functions

I have set up the eSignatures API for our app and until recently it has been working perfectly. The part that is now broken is the webhook function. So when a document gets signed by one of our clients, it triggers our webhook cloud function that then updates our database (seems simple?).

The problem is that eSignatures have now updated their timeout to only 8 seconds, which means that my function does not have enough time to run and respond to their servers. It does however still run and update the database correctly, but as it takes longer than 8 seconds, the 200 response never reaches eSignatures and therefore they retry the endpoint every hour (for ~5/6 hours). I have put in a catch so that data is not duplicated when this happens, but ideally we don't want the retries to take place!

My question is basically, is there a way to send a 200 response at the beginning of the function to eSginatures, and then continue with the updates? Or is there another solution to handle this timeout? As if anything does fail in the function, I still want to return a 4xx to eSignatures and in this case we will want the retry?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a response from your Cloud Functions and then continue executing tasks. When the response is sent, the Function is stopped. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746980/continue-execution-after-sending-response-cloud-functions-for-firebase) and [this one](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_execution_timeline)

But even if you could, sending a response before ending the tasks that your Cloud Function prevents you from sending a 4XX response if they fail. Hence, eSginatures would never retry.

I don't think you can do much else aside from possibly optimizing your Cloud Function or increasing the eSignatures timeout, which I don't think is possible ATM.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I thought to be honest! Thought i'd put it out there incase anyone has a solution! Thanks for the comment