# TypeError data.forEach is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

So when I send a get request in postman I am catching my 404 error in postman saying the "scream not found" ok great, but in my terminal I am getting this.

> TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
> at F:\dev\stfu-functions\functions\handlers\screams.js:68:18
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> i  functions: Finished "api" in ~2s
> (node:6672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (F:\dev\stfu-functions\functions\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (F:\dev\stfu-functions\functions\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (F:\dev\stfu-functions\functions\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at F:\dev\stfu-functions\functions\handlers\screams.js:75:29
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> (node:6672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by
> rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:6672) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here is my code where the error is happening Any Help is greatly apreciated.

```
exports.getScream =(req, res) => {
    let screamData = {};
    db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if(!doc.exists){
                return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Scream not found' });
            }
            screamData = doc.data();
            screamData.screamId = doc.id;
            return db
            .collection('comments')
            .where('screamId', '==', req.params.screamId)
            .get();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            screamData.comments = [];
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                screamData.comments.push(doc.data());
            });
            return res.json(screamData);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        })
};
```

Comment: Maybe don't return an object for a 404 request status, throw an error so the next `catch` handles the error.

Comment: Thanks drew gave that a shot now i caught my 500 error and terminal said this
TypeError: Cannot set property 'screamId' of undefined

Comment: I have tried your code and it worked perfectly. are you sure you are sending requests to the right endpoint? it should be something like `/:screamId`

Comment: Thanks for the response Methkal Khalawi, Yes I am sure :*(

// Scream routes
app.get('/screams', getAllScreams);
app.post('/scream', FBAuth, postOneScream);
app.get('/scream/:screamId', getScream );
//TODO: delete scream
//TODO: like a scream
//TODO: unlike a scream
app.post('/scream/:screamId/comment', FBAuth, commentOnScream)

Comment: Does it work if you follow @DrewReese suggestion and then add the rest of the code after the `if` in the first `then()` inside an `else` statement?

Comment: @JoseV thanks for the comment, but that would break the function, the function and code is running just fine, there is an issue with it retrieving the comment scream for some reason.

Comment: @Mason You should not be expecting code in your function to run after the response is sent. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749681/12163274).
This is why I suggested to place the code in an else statement. Is it possible you were expecting some code to run after the response was sent?

Comment: @JoseV hey thanks for the reply, I was using postman for a get request, I figured it out, what I ended up doing was just starting that whole side of the project over, its running fine now. but now ran into another error ha life of a programmer >_<

Comment: Good job on solving your issue! It may be useful for other users who are facing a similar issue if you post an answer with the actions that led to the resolution.

Comment: Thanks Jose, If I knew what the issue was I would have, it was probably something silly like a random , or ;  usually is.